# SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task downloader: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery, supervisord

i have added djcelery and kombu.transport.django to django apps.

### settings.py:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

from .celery import app as celery_app

BROKER_URL = "redis://abc:abc@localhost:6379/0"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Europe/London"
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

# store AsyncResult in redis
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"
REDIS_HOST = "localhost"
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = 0
REDIS_VHOST = 0 
REDIS_USER="xyz"
REDIS_PASSWORD="xyz"
REDIS_CONNECT_RETRY = True
```

### celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

from . import celeryconfig

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

app = Celery('apps')   

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

### celery supervisor configuration:

```
[program:celeryd]

command=/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/bin/python /vagrant/project/manage.py celeryd -B -E -c 1  --settings=config.settings

directory=/vagrant/project

user=vagrant

autostart=true
autorestart=true

stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celeryd_err.log
```

when a task is scheduled using django-celery interface which supposed to download some files, following errors are thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 203, in maybe_due
    result = self.apply_async(entry, publisher=publisher)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 259, in apply_async
    entry, exc=exc)), sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 251, in apply_async
    **entry.options)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 555, in apply_async
    **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 323, in send_task
    reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 302, in publish_task
    **kwargs

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 168, in publish
    routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 440, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 180, in _publish
    [maybe_declare(entity) for entity in declare]

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 111, in maybe_declare
    return maybe_declare(entity, self.channel, retry, **retry_policy)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/common.py", line 99, in maybe_declare
    return _maybe_declare(entity)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/common.py", line 110, in _maybe_declare
    entity.declare()

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 505, in declare
    self.queue_declare(nowait, passive=False)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 531, in queue_declare
    nowait=nowait)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 447, in queue_declare
    return queue_declare_ok_t(queue, self._size(queue), 0)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 651, in _size
    sizes = cmds.execute()

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2157, in execute
    conn.disconnect()

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 800, in disconnect
    channel._on_connection_disconnect(self)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 461, in _on_connection_disconnect
    self.connection.cycle._on_connection_disconnect(connection)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 259, in _on_connection_disconnect
    self.poller.unregister(connection._sock)

File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/eventio.py", line 85, in unregister
    self._epoll.unregister(fd)

SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task downloader: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

---

and i'm not getting any clue where from these errors are coming...

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

### Update 1:

i use django-celery admin interface to schedule a task and task is defined inside an app registered in INSTALLED_APP as follows:

```
@shared_task
def downloader():
    # execute static/shell_scripts/feed_downloader.sh
    import subprocess
    PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
    subprocess.call(PROJECT_PATH+"/static/shell_scripts/feed_downloader.sh", shell=True)
```

the feed_downloader.sh file calls a django management command which if i execute independetly works fine like:

```
python manage.py feed_downloader
```

if i add a print statement just before line no. 85 to check `fd` parameter in file

```
/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/eventio.py
```

then following messages get printed:

```
see this <socket._socketobject object at 0x131b750>
see this None
see this <socket._socketobject object at 0x131bc90>
see this None
```

Comment: How do you create celery task? Looks like you are passing object in arguments which can't be send through broker.

Comment: @daniula sometime scheduled tasks get executed and most of the time above errors are thrown...i also increased number of workers from 1 to 4, one or two time it worked and again starts giving errors. Is it related to worker or redis? also i added `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
    CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True`, but things didnt improved.

Comment: i've found that if schedule time is about 2 minutes or less then downloader task is executed successfully, but if its more than that then throws above argument errors. it means redis is expiring the jobs from job queue??